# solve the differential equation y'+sin(x)y=(sinx)^3, y(0)=-3 is the initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with the following differential equation,

$y'+sin(x)y=(sin(x))^3$

First I have determined that the answer is something like:

$y(x)=c(x)* e^{cos(x)}$, but now I have to determine the '$c(x)$' term,
The last integral which I have to solve now is :
$\frac{dc(x)}{dx}= (sin(x))^3\times e^{-cos(x)}$, but i don't know how, the only hint which is given is:
$((u+1)^2\times e^{-u})'=(1-u^2)e^{-u}$, but I don't know how to use this hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your last equation is missing a factor of $u'$, it should be

$( (u+1)^2 \times e^{-u} )' = (1-u^2) \times u' \times e^{-u} $

Using this you can write

$ \frac{dc(x)}{dx} = \sin(x)^2  \sin(x) e^{-\cos(x)} = (1-\cos(x)^2 ) \times \sin(x)  \times e^{-\cos(x)} = (  (1+ \cos(x) )^2 \times e^{-\cos(x)} )'$.